# Baked Apple Fritter

Tags: baking, yeast, apples, doughnuts

I know I know I know... apple fritters SHOULD be fried.

I'm just here asking for any tips or suggestions to as-close-as-possible obtain the next best thing by baking apple fritters in an oven. I'd like to get a similar mouthfeel as well as visual.

Any recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This one could be tricky - the mouthfeel of a fritter is to some degree associated with the oil content from the frying. The trick with fritters is that the cooking of the outside is quick so that it doesn't massively deform or separate into small pieces when placed into the hot oil.

Having said that, it may be possible to get this feel by putting a relatively heavy spray of oil onto the baking surface and then pre-heating this in the oven, then adding the batter and baking, perhaps spraying the top surface as well to increase heat transfer and shorten baking time so that the batter retains its shape. You may find that something like a panini press or a waffle maker gives a better result.